# php json_decode returning infinite

Tags: php, json

If I run the following, no error is returned and the value of $result is `INF`. `json_last_error()` returns `0`.

`$result = json_decode('547533e683433', true);`

As this is a string and not JSON I would expect `$result` to be `NULL` and `json_last_error()` to return `4` or `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well, what do you expect it to return?

Comment: `547533e683433` is a *huge* number.  547533 x10^683433

Comment: I would expect json_last_error() to return an error code, in this case it should be 4 (JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX) and the $result to be NULL. I'll update the question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat So huge, that PHP thinks it is infinitive and returns it as `INF`

Comment: @greg: According to [the docs](http://php.net/json_decode), `[PHP] will also encode and decode scalar types and NULL`.  So it's trying to decode `'547533e683433'` as an int, but it's so big that it gives you infinity.

Comment: but it is a string, not a number?

Comment: Not a full dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19236155/3933332

Comment: @greg: It's a number.  The `e` means "times `10^y`".  So, `3e2` is `3x10^2`.  See the docs for [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php): Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value.

Comment: @greg: Also when decoding, `'1'` is a number and `'"1"'` is a string.

Comment: Why the down votes? It seems like a legitimate question to me? @RocketHazmat your answers have been great, add as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @greg I think the problem was, that the users, didn't see what your question was/ what you wanted, so it might was unclear to them. (But sadly I'm out of votes for today, otherwise you and Rocket Hazmat would get an upV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected result.  While `'547533e683433'` is not valid JSON, PHP can still "decode" it.

> PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original RFC
>   4627 - it will also encode and decode scalar types and NULL.

According to the docs for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode), PHP will decode single scalar values, not just arrays/objects.

In the case of `'547533e683433'`, it's interpreted as an *int* when decoding (strings need to be in double quotes).  `547533e683433` is read as `547533 x 10^683433` (see the docs for [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)), which is a huge number.  PHP can't represent a number this big, so it gives you `INF`.